# Not able to debug activator with war file in Wildfly (JBoss 9.0.2) in STS

Tags: playframework, wildfly

I am totally new to play framework.I am not even sure weather I am on right path with debugging.
Using Wildfly (JBoss 9.0.2), play latest version( activator).Have placed my war files for service and web(play project) in Wildfly's standalone -->deployments folder.
Application is working fine.Issue is I cannot debug the application. Have created a new debug configuration under Remote Java Application with host as localhost, port as 8787, source I am adding two projects web and service.
As war files are placed in wildfly and which runs at port 8787 have mentioned this port number in debug configuration.
It was working fine few days back, I was able to debug my play as well as service side code with above debug configuration.But now(since past two days) debug points are not working at all.

Tried adding fork in run := false in build.sbt , it din't help.

How should I debug this application with wildfly and activator.I am just running the jboss server and deploying the application in local.This is the way it works , do not want to run separate play application and  service application.
Totally at my wits end with this.Please suggest something.

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Start wildfly with the --debug option in command line.

Comment: adding --debug didn't help.I checked out new project from GIT and play part of project is debugging.Service was not debugging at all, then added new Remote Java Application with same configuration which was  already created for play .Then I am able to debug both play and service project code.How this works I am still not sure.Also I added src folder of service in add source option wile debugging with search subfolder option as checked.